# code first, multiple bindings

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I would like to map my entity class to a database table.
Table rows are: Id, IsActive, BelongsToId
(BelongsToId is a foreign key)
Entity properies are: Id, IsActive, BelongsToId, BelongsTo
(BelongsToId int, BelongsTo is an other entity class' instance)
Is it possible to bind both BelongsToId and BelongsTo properties to BelongsToId data attribute? How?
I try like this, but BelongsToId's value is zero:

```
    partial class KeyConfig : EntityConfiguration<Entities.Key>
    {

    public KeyConfig ( )
    {
        Property(s => s.Id).IsIdentity();
        Relationship(s => s.BelongsTo).FromProperty(s => s.Keywords);
        Property(s => s.IsActive);
        Map();
    }

    void Map ( ) {
        MapHierarchy(s => new
        {
            s.Id,
            BelongsToId=s.BelongsTo.Id,
            s.IsActive,
        }).ToTable("Keywords");
    }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of configuration are you using? Doesn't seem like Entity Framework CodeFirst to me. Why is your configuration `partial`?

Comment: i have a DataContext class where i initialize a ContextBuilder:
   var builder = new ContextBuilder<DataAccess.MyObjectContext>();
...
   builder.Configurations.Add(new DataAccess.CodeOnly.KeyConfig());

Comment: What is your EF CodeFirst version?

Comment: CTP 4.0 :S
i cant change it unfortunately